# Pycharm is not showing Pygame properties

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, pycharm

I am tring to make a game with pygame. But in editor it does not show suggestions of pygame, it just shows the older used properties. But the program is working perfect. I am not sure but i think the problem is in interpreter. The interpreter is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe. I am using pycharm 2020.1

[image]

It can find pygame, but not its properties

[image]

It is showing some properties which are i already used in other lines, but not others

EDIT: I have learned it is also not showing tkinter's properties. But other modules work good.

Comment: Could you please attach a code sample or screenshot? PyCharm use static analysis for code insight, and sometimes classes, functions, attributes and even modules are initialized dynamically hence PyCharm is unable to find them.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, but there is a problem. It was working well for a long time. What may be happened now?

Comment: Have you updated PyCharm and/or pygame?

Comment: I have updated Pycharm to version 2020.1